# Child navigation sidebar or drop-down navigation displaying child items

Tags: routes, navigation, 7

I have a 'basic page' which is a parent and is provided a menu link. This page has several children (subpages).

How would I display the subpages for each nav item either in the following cases?

- Drop-down menu from the main navigation menu, or some close alternative
- Display all the children for that page in a sidebar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Drop-down menu from the main navigation menu, or some close
>   alternative

Use [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish). It integrates the jQuery Superfish dropdown plugin with your Drupal menus.

> Display all the children for that page in a sidebar

Use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block). It provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu. And more!

Comment: Thank you. They both look like good solutions. I went for Menu Block.