# Inside drop-down menu child menus are not working

Tags: 8, navigation, bootstrap-theme

I am using bootstrap sub-theme and created a drop-down menu and set it's menu levels they are working correctly but when i extend to child menus it's  not working.
I have searched [Expand menu links down in a tree](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130834/expand-menu-links-down-in-a-tree) and [Child navigation sidebar or drop-down navigation displaying child items](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26654/child-navigation-sidebar-or-drop-down-navigation-displaying-child-items) but not found any solution.

Any Help?

[image: Main Menu]

[image: Child Menu]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 and 4 have dropped support for nested (multilevel) menus

One has to include the relevant code (that was excluded) in their own custom theme to make it work.

Check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing) for relevant code to add to your theme

NOTE: the reason the support was dropped is that multilevel nesting is problematic in mobile or smaller screens so you have to implement solutions for small screens on your own.

Comment: Let me check @GiorgosK

Comment: Thank You GiorgosK the answer works for me. Only a bit amendment at  http://varpuniversity.twinkleblink.com/  . It's not stable on hover i will fix it soon.